# When I Start XAMPP its Give Me a Some Errors

Tags: windows, xampp

Whenever i start my xampp it gives me some errors of MYSQL.
cant understood what happened here.
i Uninstall Xampp and Reintall, But situation is Same.

I Installed It **C:\xampp**.

Pls Give Me Some Insrtuction To Solve This Problems.
Thanks..

[image]

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
```

Its Also Give Error Like.. **mysqld.exe has stopped working**

Answer (score 0):

you have Open config. File And httpd.conf And httpd-ssl.config file And Change Port httpd.config Port :-8080 Write Them Your Port No any 
Ssl.config File And Changes Port:-443 Then Change Port No:-4433

Comment: Thanks for your help. but. Nothing Happened I DO That suggest u.

Answer (score 0):

Open Config File For Apache
An Open httpd.config File And Find Port:-
And Then Display A Port No:-80 And give This Port No no. 8000

Second File Open httpd-ssl Config  File And Find Port And Display Port :-443
And Give This Port No.4433 And Restart The Xampp And Open Apache And Apache Server IS Working Properly